# holonomic constraint and equation of $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 16$.

Tags: mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

A particle of mass, $m$, moves in three dimensions on the surface of a sphere defined by the
equation $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 16$.

Defining the trajectory of the particle by $r(t) = r_x \hat{e}_x + r_y \hat{e}_y + r_z \hat{e}_z$

(I'm not sure how to format properly but e should have ^ above it in the equation above)

give the constraint equation for the particle’s motion and state, with explanation, whether it is a holonomic constraint or a non-holonomic constraint.

Also I've never use this site before so if I messed up anything as in tags or anything let me know. I have no idea where to start here so please explain it in as simple terms as you can. Thank you

Comment: I recommend a look in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints

Comment: the x,y,z are meant to be subscripts for ex, ey, ez. also there is meant to be a ^ above the e but the rest is right